# Scrollbar separating page into 2 using php

Tags: php, include, scrollbar

I've got a file which I want to separate between an image at the top of the page and rows of data relating to the image which form the detail of the page. I want the user to be able to scroll down the data whilst simultaneously viewing the image.

Unfortunately simple scrolling on the page won't work because there are in fact two unjoined tables side by side making up the detail and when I put a simple scrollbar only one table scrolls at a time.

To get round this problem I thought of having the detail as an php include file, and tried to place the file between iframe tags as one would with an html file which should allow the whole include file to be scrolled.

I was able to do the following with an html file but found that I could not change the code to accomodate a php file. Anyone any suggestions, gratefully received.

main body of code for image file followed by the following which inserts a html file which I can scroll

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:920px; width:500px; height:37px;">
    <?php
    $iframe_doc = '/entry_forms.html';
    ?>
    <iframe src="<?php echo $iframe_doc; ?>" width="1500" height="200" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</div>
```

I would like to have simply inserted a similar file called `entry_forms.php` where it says `entry_forms.html` and substitute echo for include but the output only includes the html portion of the file and not the data, if that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use PHP include in the `src=""` attribute of the iframe. Use it between the opening and closing tats of the `<iframe>` to render contents into it.

Comment: sorry can you elaborate @marekful. As it stands does my code not sit between the two tags? <iframe> and </iframe> Thanks for responding.

Comment: I'm not sure what the value of `$iframe_doc` is but if it's not a **path name** to a file that you'd like to be the source document of the iframe but it's the **contents** you'd like to display within the iframe, then you should: `<iframe ... ><?php include $iframe_doc ?></iframe>`

Comment: You are correct marekful that is my intention. I've been playing about with what I thought you were suggesting but whilst it is giving me a frame there is no content.

        <?php

        $iframe_doc = 'entry_forms.php';




        ?>






        <iframe><?php include $iframe_doc; ?></iframe>

        </div>

Perhaps just a syntax error?

Comment: My next thought was to pass the variables in the url. I don't know whether something like the following can be done. The code works when I put it in the URL window of my browser. Can it be done this way?

``<?php
echo '<iframe align="left" width=1800 height=300 src="stages_detail.php."?pn=' . $sub1 . '&jrny='.$jrny.'&Subject='.$Subject.'&pn2='.$sub1. '&arc='.$sess.'&Table_Id='.$Table_Id; 'frameborder="yes" scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"></iframe>'; 


?>``

Comment: Pleased to say worked it out as follows, basic premise was correct, just had to fiddle with syntax

``<?php

$src = 'stages_detail.php?pn=' . $sub1 . '&jrny='.$jrny.'&Subject='.$Subject.'&pn2='.$sub1. '&arc='.$sess.'&Table_Id='.$Table_Id;

echo '<iframe align="center" width=1900 height= 300 src="'.$src.'" frameborder="yes" scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"> </iframe>';
?>``